# Reading a delimited text file with blank column

Tags: sas

I'm trying to read a pipe delimited text file in SAS with following code :

```
Data MyData;
Infile MyFile Dsd Dlm= '|' Firstobs= 2 Termstr = CRLF Truncover;
Input A: $30.
  B: 2.
  C: $30.
  D: $30.
  E: 2.;
Run;
```

Column A to C are definitely present for each record but columns D and E may or may not be present. The file is delimited in a way that there is a pipe between two inputs but not after the end of a line.

An example is shown below.

```
 A1|4|C1|D1|5A2|7|C2A3|3|C3|D3|1A4 ...
```

How do I read this file where the last two inputs are optional? I don't want to use Proc Import because it's a large file and the columns A, B and C have a range of values that Proc Import isn't able to handle very well (as per my experience).

My current code causes some of the values from column A to be pulled into column D when there are missing values.

Comment: Your sample data appear to have no line breaks - did you forget to include one? If there are no line breaks, why are you using `termstr=CRLF` ?

Comment: You are missing the semi-colon to end the `input` statement. You current code will try to create a numeric variable named `Run`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the input statement in your example is correct?  As it stands now, column B and column E are using numeric informats, but the data example appears to be character.

Comment: Apologies. My input statement was posted incorrectly but wasn't the problem. The sample data breaks over into the next line after multiple iterations of the same structure.The solution below was able to solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, there's some indication of when E ends.  Some EOL character (maybe one you can't see).  If so, then you can use that as a delimiter.

If there's no way to tell when E ends, then you will need to figure it out from business logic (what kind of value exists in E and in A).  If E is only 2 long, then you can process the field using the `_INFILE_` variable.  Something like this might work, if the total line length is <= 32767:

```
data want;
  infile 'h:\test.txt' dlm='|'; *infile with dlm statement as usual;
  input @@;                     *open input pointer;
  call scan(_infile_,5*_N_,pos,len,'|',); *find where the 5Nth field is;
  _infile_ = cat(substr(_infile_,1,pos+1),'|',substr(_infile_,pos+2));
                                *Insert a | there;
  input a: $30.
        b: 11.
        c: $5.
        d: $5.
        e: 2.
        @@
        ;                       *note the @@ holding the input pointer;
run;
```